# appending more than one value after preg_split

Tags: php

Im running a  loop to insert a column from csv file .The csv file contains a column with values like

```
India
srilanka
china taiwan
USA UK France
china japan
```

I split the column using preg_split function ,to split based on empty spaces

```
preg_split('/\s+/', $countries);
```

After splitting i get the output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => India
)
Array
(
    [0] => srilanka
)
Array
(
    [0] => USA
    [1] => UK
    [2] => France
)

Array
(
    [0] => china
    [1] => japan

)
```

each array if it contains more than one value it should append 2nd and third with opening and closing braces

I want to have final value as

```
india
srilanka
USA(UK France)
China(japan)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want. This gets each line as argument, not the array. So you don't have to do the preg_split:

```
function split_countries($line) {
    $split = explode(" ", $line);
    $ret = array_shift($split);
    if (count($split)) {
        $ret .= "(" . implode(" ", $split) . ")";
    }
    return $ret;
}

echo split_countries("India") . "\n";
echo split_countries("USA UK France") . "\n";
```